# Add link to image via javascript

Tags: javascript, image

Can someone help me add a link to an image that I am adding via Javascript? I know this should be something simple but I can't get it to work.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/zycu86f6/)

```
<div class="toggle-panel">
Hi there!
</div>

var img = new Image();
var div = document.querySelector('.toggle-panel');
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.com'); 

img.onload = function() {
div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/2603/weezle/256/weezle_sun.png';

link.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: you should replace "div.appendChild(img);" with "div.appendChild(link);".

Comment: $('a').attr("href","www.google.com");

Answer (score 0):

You still need to add the link to the div, like this:

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.querySelector('.toggle-panel');
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.com'); 

img.src = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/2603/weezle/256/weezle_sun.png';

link.appendChild(img);
div.appendChild(link);
```

No need to do it on the image's onload event.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zycu86f6/3/).